# Select rows that are "different" than the previous row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database in this format:

```
id    id_user     name           date

1  | 12       | barney | 2012-03-15 12:50:10 |
2  | 12       | barney | 2012-03-15 13:50:10 |
3  | 12       | barney | 2012-03-15 14:50:10 |
4  | 13       | roger  | 2012-03-15 15:50:10 |
```

All I want to do, is to check whether there is the possibility of **select the id WHERE id_user is different to id_user selected previous**.

If I do this, I can select only the id: **'1'** and **'4'** of my table *(the id's '2' and '3' not selected but I don't want to pick the id of the same id_user who I selected previous)*, I wonder if it is possible to do this kind of thing directly by sql syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table_name 
where id in (select min(id) from table_name group by id_user)
```

Comment: This is not a correct answer, even though it works with the provided data. Additional work is needed to handle this case correctly.

Comment: It was just exactly what I wanted to do thank you very much for your help I am very grateful!

Comment: +1 . . . I interpret "select the id WHERE id_user is different to id_user selected previous" as "select the id where id_user is different from previously selected id_users".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id
FROM TABLE_NAME AS t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE_NAME AS t2 ON t1.id_user =t2.id_user
AND t1.date < t2.date
WHERE t2.id_user IS NULL
```

I think this would do.

Comment: Try now. I also used name in join.

Comment: Man you are confusing me, The very first query will give the desired output :/